# Loader before jQuery page load

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a loader to be visible until the document is fully loaded, but the loader dissapear before page fully loaded.

```
<div  class="loader">
    <div class="spinner">
        <div class="rect1"></div>
        <div class="rect2"></div>
        <div class="rect3"></div>
        <div class="rect4"></div>
        <div class="rect5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js used is :

```
    $("#continut").load("fbapp.php");
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.loader').fadeOut();
    });
```

Any ideea why the loader is fading out before the #continut is loaded ?

Comment: put the fadeout into a callback function of the continut load call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.load` does not take in to account AJAX requests, only external CSS files, images etc. To do what you require, use the callback of the `load()` method:

```
$("#continut").load('fbapp.php', function () {
    $('.loader').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$().load(url)` makes an *ajax* call - ie asynchronous.

Your window has finished loading, but the additional ajax call has not.  `window` does not get events from ajax load.

You can use the 'done' part of [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), as in:

```
$("#continut").load("fbapp.php", function () {
    $('.loader').fadeOut();
});
```